# Dividing square of 2013x2013

Tags: geometry

> Is the square of 2013×2013 can be divided into rectangles 1×3 in such
>   a way that the number of rectangles arranged vertically differ by 1
>   from the number rectangles arranged horizontally? Prove your answer

I totally have no idea how to solve that. I need accurate solutions or good hints.

Comment: Try using 3x3 blocks to reduce the rectangle to a size you can reason about.

Comment: Try determining the prime factors of 2013.

Comment: @stevemarvell 2013 = 3 · 11 · 61

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $2013$ is divisble by $3$, show by complete induction that the number of vertical bars that extend upward starting with bottom base at row $k$ must be divisible by $3$. Then you will get that the total number of vertical bars is divisible by $3$, and by symmetry, the number of horizontal bars that extend rightward starting with base column $k$ must be divisible by $3$, so the total number of horizontal bars must also be divisible by $3$, so they cannot differ by $1$.

Comment: Ok, thank you, can I give me an example of induction ? Maybe formulas ?